# How can I use a function parameter to define a customEvent in facebook conversion API

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, gravityforms

I want to record in Facebook event manager which questions a user exits. Gravity Forms provides the function below; it runs your code block when a user moves to the next question on the form.

```
jQuery(document).on('gform_page_loaded', function (event, form_id, current_page) {
// my code here
});
```

Facebook recommends to use the following snippet to record a custom event in event manager.

```
fbq('trackCustom', 'ShareDiscount', {promotion: 'share_discount_10%'});
// ShareDiscount is the custom event name
```

I need the event name defined using the `current_page` parameter value from the Gravity Forms function. When I `console.log(current_page)`, I see the expected value in the console. However, Facebook doesn't recognize the event when I try to use the parameter in the Facebook fbq code. Example:

```
// NOT WORKING - facebook doesn't record the event
jQuery(document).on(
  'gform_page_loaded',
  function (event, form_id, current_page) {
    console.log(current_page); // console logs current_page as expected
    return fbq('trackCustom', `${current_page}`, {
      futureUse: 'to_be_defined_later',
    });
  }
);
```

When I use just a static string, Facebook records the event as expected. But I need the current page value to be used allowing event names to be defined dynamically using the `current_page` parameter.

```
// WORKING - facebook records the static string as an event
jQuery(document).on(
  'gform_page_loaded',
  function (event, form_id, current_page) {
    return fbq('trackCustom', 'Static Event Name', {
      futureUse: 'to_be_defined_later',
    });
  }
);
```

I have tried the `current_page.toString()` method without luck. Without duplicating code in a many `if` statements, how can one dynamically define the custom event name?

Comment: Do you get any console info or error?

Comment: And also could you share what does " console.log(current_page);" displays?

Comment: I do not get console info nor errors. When I console.log(current_page) I get a number. The form in question is https://www.vantagetrials.com/sciatica-study/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-pixel/implementation/conversion-tracking#custom-events) for custom event names:

> Custom event names must be strings, and cannot exceed 50 characters in length.

Well, since you've tried converting it to string, I'd say it also has a **minimum** character length (that should be greater than one or two)...Try something like this:

```
  function (event, form_id, current_page) {
    return fbq('trackCustom', 'MyEventName-' + current_page, {
      futureUse: 'to_be_defined_later',
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works! However, I don't know why. 

Why doesn't current_page alone work? 
Why didn't it work when using template literals or toString() method?
I have so much to learn.

Comment: I've assumed they have some unwritten rules, like they wouldn't allow you to call an event "1" or "2"...even if it's a string. Well, we all do have so much to learn, that why we are here, I'm glad I could help you a little bit :)